# How to check directory size?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to check the size of the folder with Rust?

I didn't see such method mentioned.
I can do it via invoking a shell command but I prefer to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 10):

crate `fs_extra` seems to work well for me https://docs.rs/fs_extra/1.2.0/fs_extra/dir/fn.get_size.html

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
fs_extra = "1.2.0"
```

code

```
extern crate fs_extra;
use fs_extra::dir::get_size;

fn main(){
  let folder_size = get_size("dir").unwrap();
  println!("{}", folder_size); // print directory sile in bytes
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Could you explain what you mean more specifically? Do you just want to get a `du`-like information (recursively sum the size of each file)?

In that case you probably want to use `std::fs::read_dir`, iterate on the entries, sum the sizes (via metadata) of the non-directories, and recurse into directories.

I'm pretty sure there is no builtin `du`, I don't think there even is a builtin recursive directory walker (hence [walkdir](https://docs.rs/walkdir/2.3.1/walkdir/))

Comment: In general - yes.

But `read_dir` will return a ReadDir which I can iterate on it ... and provides me no way to check the size of a directory.
(And if this directory we have more directories and inside them even more ones - do I have to recursively iterate and sum the sizes of all files inside?)

Comment: "do I have to recursively iterate and sum the sizes of all files inside?" yes. ReadDir is an iterator of DirEntry, then you can check each direntry, fetch its size if it's a file and recursively get *its* entries if it's a directory. Note that give your needs you probably don't need to recursively iterate, you can just push directory entries on a stack, then pop entries from the stack to check them.

Comment: There is a du crate for rust.

https://docs.rs/crate/du/0.1.1

Answer (score 3):

Either you use a crate, or you calculate it by hand, with something like that (recursive solution):

```
use std::{fs, io, path::PathBuf};

fn dir_size(path: impl Into<PathBuf>) -> io::Result<u64> {
    fn dir_size(mut dir: fs::ReadDir) -> io::Result<u64> {
        dir.try_fold(0, |acc, file| {
            let file = file?;
            let size = match file.metadata()? {
                data if data.is_dir() => dir_size(fs::read_dir(file.path())?)?,
                data => data.len(),
            };
            Ok(acc + size)
        })
    }

    dir_size(fs::read_dir(path.into())?)
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    println!("{}", dir_size(".")?);

    Ok(())
}
```